# Reading number from a string

Tags: c, string

I have problem with string reading. From `Hell13 World` i need to get the number 13.

```
while (*znak){
   if (isdigit(*znak)){
    x=*znak - '0';
    printf("%d\n", x);
   }
    *dst++ = * znak;
    znak ++;
    }
```

with my solution, i get number 1 and number 3 separately.

Comment: case of `Hell1 World3` also get `13` ?

Comment: Of course you are getting the numbers separately, because you check digits with `if`. If you want to look at sequences of consecutive digits, you should use `while`. (On the digits, that is. The overall `while` is for traversing the whole string.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get the first digit and then print it. After seeing a digit you must loop until you see no more digits.

```
if (isdigit(*znak)){
    while (*znak && isdigit(*znak))
        x= x*10 + *znak++ - '0';
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Comment: The double check for `*znak` (I wonder what it means?) is not necessary, because `isdigit(0)` should already be false.

Comment: You're right, isdigit(0) will be false. Just a nasty habit to check for end-of-string...